# Variable passing using super() in Python

Tags: python, oop

I thought I understood how this would work but apparently I don't. Take this example:

File 1 (sandbox.py):

```
from module1 import Testy

class Sandy(Testy):
    def run(self):
        print("This is value of x in Sandy: %d" % x)
        super(Sandy, self).mymet()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = 4
    test = Sandy()
    test.run()
```

File 2 (module1.py):

```
class Testy(object):
    def mymet(self):
        print("This is the value of x in Testy %d: " % x)
```

This is what I receive back in the console when running sandbox.py:

> This is value of x in Sandy: 4 
>   NameError: global name 'x' is not defined

Is the best/only way of doing this to pass the x argument explicitly to mymet() in the parent class?

Comment: you need to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's not how scoping works. You can't access locals from other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass it to both functions as a parameter:

```
class Testy(object):
    def mymet(self, x):
        print("This is the value of x in Testy %d: " % x)

class Sandy(Testy):
    def run(self, x):
        print("This is value of x in Sandy: %d" % x)
        super(Sandy, self).mymet(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = 4
    test = Sandy()
    test.run(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is obviously a fundamental misunderstanding on my part. I believe in my case above I would only need to pass x into mymet() and wouldn't need to pass x into Sandy().run().
I guess I assumed this could be made available without explicitly passing it through - but seems I'm wrong.

Comment: @JPow You could bypass `test.run(x)` and call `mymet` directly with `test.mymet(x)` but you still need to pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is your base class `Testy`

the variable `x` is not defined in class scope and so it doesn't exist in your subclasses.

```
class Testy(object):
    self.x = 4
    def mymet(self):
        print("This is the value of x in Testy %d: " % self.x)
```